# Facebook SDK with Javascript failing, cannot tell why

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is my simple html:

fb_driver.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>Facebook Driver</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fb_driver.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        alert("why can i not see this?");
        FB.init({
          appId: 'my-app-id',
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.0'
        });
        FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript'
        });
        alert("hi");
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      alert("hello");
    </script>
    <div id="fb-something" class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is essentially copied directly from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0. The "hello" alert at the end of the script shows, but the "why can i not see this?" and the "hi" do not (they are inside window.fbAsyncInit = function() {...}). "why can i not see this?" is literally the first thing inside the fbAsyncInit block but still fails to show. Can someone help me with why this is not working?

One thing I can think of is that, even though the above link says nothing needs to be imported or downloaded and just need regular javascript, perhaps there is something in earlier instructions that I missed.

Comment: the my-app-id is replaced by the app id from my app dashboard

Answer (score -1):

It ended up being that the '//' before 'connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' is no good for just opening the html file locally (which is what I'm doing just for playing around right now). I added 'http:' so it reads 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js' and that got me to a different bug, which is progress.

Comment: that's a **temporary** solution doesn't specify the protocol! let's say you will switch to SSL and use `https` this will cause security issues and the SDK won't be loaded, [Mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent)